# SQL Graph, shortest path Algorithm?

Tags: sql, algorithm, graph

I found this [link](http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html#traversal) about algorithms in SQL, but none of them solved my problem: I must find shortest path between all nodes in given list. (and not only the shortest distance between the start and end node). 
As an example, I give a graph. I have to start from "A" point and visit all the red nodes, but with such an order that the total distance is the shortest. I have defined distance between every two nodes in graph.
Looking for an idea or a guideline?

[image: Graph]

Comment: You can go for Floyd Warshal, it gives shortest path between all nodes. U might have to modify a little for it to work for only 5 nodes..

Comment: not all.I have a list that is a subset of all nodes. Each time it is different list, but between all nodes  distance is always defined.

Comment: So, you want the shortest path between all the nodes in the list?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to deal with hierarchical data in SQL. Perhaps you could show us some sample data and expected output?

Comment: I have table with 3 columns: "FromNode", "ToNode", "Distance" and
table with all nodes ("Id", "Name"). I must find shortest path between nodes given in list.. (I must "visit" all of given nodes)..

Answer (score 0):

This is **a** answer (or an idea, or a guideline, as asked), not **the** answer.

1. Calculate shortest paths between all of the `red` nodes and keep the paths and their lengths for later.
2. Construct new graph with only the `red` nodes where *distance between two nodes* is their *shortest path* from the step 1.
3. In the new graph you have to solve the `traveling salesman problem`

By those three steps the original, *specific*, problem has been converted to a well known, well studied, general problem (that is NP, so no optimal solution for you for an arbitrary subset of nodes using a classical hardware).